# Abuse of image upload and resize function

Tags: image, resize

I am concerned about the allowing people to upload images to my server. I will be running a site that will allow users to do upload image which are then resized and saved on the server.

However, there is the potential for abuse here because if someone wanted to write a script to constantly bombard my server then not only would I end up with a huge number of images left on my server, but the server would become overloaded from all the resize operations.

This is a process that I was considering:

1. Image gets uploaded to a "tmp" location
2. On successful payment, image is resized and moved from "tmp" to the image folder
3. "tmp" folder cleaned out every night

Is this paranoid, overcomplicated, or does it in fact make perfect sense? Any feedback is appareciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just include a Captcha or Captcha-Like function. Since scripts can't read images, only humans can complete Captchas.

Check these out:

- http://www.captcha.net/
- http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_captcha_protection.php

Comment: Yup true, but these are always such a horrible experience for the user to have to type these in :(

Comment: I know but it seems like a faster and easier solution than creating a whole drive just as a "tmp" location.